# Manipulating symbols in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

I am trying to take an array of symbols,

```
a = [:apple, :banana ,:grape, :black]
```

and add a string at the end of each symbol depending on the last letter. If the symbol ends with `e`, add `"hello"`, otherwise `"hi"`. I want to get:

```
[:applehello, :bananahi]
```

I did:

```
n = []
a.each do |b|
  if (b[-1] == "e")
    n.push b.to_s + "hello"
  else
    n.push b.to_s + "hi"
  end
end
p n
```

I have to convert it into strings. How can I get the final output in symbols?

Did it using sub aswell-

```
a.each do |q|


if (q[-1]=="e")
    then n.push q.to_s.sub(/e/,"ehello")
  else
    n.push q.to_s.sub(/\z/,"ahi")
  end
end

p n
```

Comment: The comment by Ursus is correct. You need to convert each Symbol to a String so you can mutate it, then convert that new string to a Symbol.

Comment: What happened with `:grape` and `:black` in `a`?

Answer (score 4):

Use `to_sym` to have a symbol back

```
a = [:apple, :banana , :grape, :black]
a.map do |s|
  (s.to_s + (s[-1] == 'e' ? 'hello' : 'hi')).to_sym
end
```

An alternative

```
a = [:apple, :banana , :grape, :black]
a.map do |s|
  "#{s}#{s[-1] == 'e' ? 'hello' : 'hi'}".to_sym
end
```

Comment: Thank you +1 What f I wanted to do this via sub or gsub?

Comment: Which part? It doesn't seem work for sub/gsub though

Comment: The same code but by using gsub or sub to check the last letter and put hi or hello

Comment: Thing is we're doing more a concatenation than a substitution. Another way would be `"#{s}#{s[-1] == 'e' ? 'hello' : 'hi'}".to_sym`

Comment: Or even `:"#{s}#{s[-1] == 'e' ? 'hello' : 'hi'}"` but the leading colon will probably get lost in all the punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Tried with following,

```
a.map { |x| "#{x}#{x.to_s.last == 'e' ? 'hello' : 'hi'}".to_sym }
# => [:applehello, :bananahi, :grapehello, :blackhi]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.map{|sym| sym.to_s.sub(/.\z/) do
  |c| case c; when "e" then "hello"; else "hi" end.to_sym
end}
# => [:applhello, :bananhi, :graphello, :blachi]
```

Comment: Add some explanation please.

Comment: the OP does not seem to want to lose the last character but rather just append hello/hi

Comment: I put up my solution using sub